# maximum likelihood method for generalized mixed effects model

Tags: mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, maximum-likelihood

reference: http://www.stat.wisc.edu/~bates/UseR2008/WorkshopD.pdf from page 120.

Now I want to fit a generalized logistic mixed model, where $\beta$ is fixed effect, $\theta$ is variance covariance parameter of random effects, $u$ is the random effects, $\tilde{u}$ is the empirical random effects. The likelihood function is $$L(\theta, \beta \mid y) = \int p(y \mid X,\beta, Z, u) \; p(u \mid \theta) \, du.$$

I do not understand how fixed effects $\beta$ and variance parameters of random effects $\theta$ are estimated. According to the slides, first they use penalized iteratively reweighted leases squares method to estimate $\tilde{u}(y|\theta,\beta)$, then use Laplace approximation and maximum likelihood method to maximum deviance $d(\beta,\theta|y)$. The deviance is a function of $y,\tilde{u}$, then a function of $y,\beta,\theta$.

From my perspective, $\tilde{u}$ is not a closed form. How can we mamimize a function where the function includes a PIRLS algorithm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, classical maximum likelihood estimation of the parameters in generalized linear mixed effects models requires a combination of numerical integration and numerical optimization. The numerical integration is requires because the integral in the specification of the marginal likelihood function, as you wrote above, does not have a closed-form solution.

For this numerical integration the adaptive Gaussian quadrature is considered one of the best approaches to approximate the involved integrals. The *adaptive* part of the rule has to do with appropriately centering and scaling the integrands. This step requires locating the mode of the conditional likelihood $$L(u \mid y; \beta, \theta) = p(y \mid u, \beta) \; p(u \mid \theta).$$ In this step PIRLS is used. Then when you have approximated the integral, you optimize the marginal log-likelihood $\ell(\beta, \theta) = \sum_i \log L_i(\beta, \theta \mid y_i, X_i, Z_i)$ you wrote above.

The degree of the approximation in the adaptive Gaussian quadrature rule is controlled by the number of quadrature points. The Laplase approximation is equivalent to 1 quadrature point (and this is why it often does not perform that well, especially for binary data and Poisson data will low expected counts).

Comment: Thank you! I am still confused about one point. When PIRLS is used, $\beta$ and $\theta$ are unknown because they are what we want to estimate in the second step. But if the input is unknown, how do I use PIRLS? To be specific, how do I determine the number of steps of PIRLS?

Comment: The procedure works iteratively, you start with initial values for $\beta$ and $\theta$ and for these you calculate the modes $\hat u$ using PIRLS. Then given these modes you do the Laplace approximation and you update the values for $\beta$ and $\theta$. And you continue alternating these two steps until convergence.

Comment: Thank you, professor! By the way, the procedure looks like an EM algorithm. Estimating $\tilde{u}$ and Laplace approximation, i.e. the numerical integration is the E-step. And maximizing log-likelihood is the M-step. Is this correct?

Comment: Even though it seems like it, this is not an EM algorithm.